# How could this be the first time Percy Jackson learned he could do this?

Tags: percy-jackson

### Be able to healed by water

When Percy Jackson is in [Camp Half-Blood](http://riordan.wikia.com/wiki/Camp_Half-Blood) he is role-playing a battle against another team as a training exercise. Just as he is about to get to the final goal he gets into dual with [Annabeth Chase](http://riordan.wikia.com/wiki/Annabeth_Chase). She beats him down and he is injured. A voice (which turns out to be his father, [Poseidon](http://riordan.wikia.com/wiki/Poseidon)) tells him to go to the water, where he uses the water's power to heal himself.

Going along with the story of the movie, it certainly seems that this is the first time he does this as Percy himself is surprised.

But, I am sure growing up he would have hurt himself before and just taking a bath or even going for a swim would have healed any of his injuries big or small. Surely he would have realized this long before going to Camp Half Blood?

Comment: Is it possible that this water (in particular) has some kind of special effect? He seems a so-so fighter before and a born-again-badass afterwards.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Demigods don't have their full powers until they're acknowledged by their parents.

The problem here is that when adapting the film from the books, they (sadly) cut a few important things, including explaining why Percy wasn't able to heal himself with water before this point and why he didn't know about his other abilities earlier.

The short answer is that demigods don't have their full powers until they're *acknowledged* by their parents. It was only when Percy fought against worthy opponents (other demigods) while standing in water that he was fully and  officially acknowledged by his father Poseidon.

[image: Percy claimed]

> ‘Look, I – I don’t know why,’ I said, trying to apologize. ‘I’m sorry…’
>   But they weren’t watching my wounds heal. They were staring at something above my head.
>   ‘Percy,’ Annabeth said, pointing. ‘Um…’
>   **By the time I looked up, the sign was already fading, but I could still make out the hologram of green light, spinning and gleaming. A three-tipped spear: a trident.**
>   ‘Your father,’ Annabeth murmured. ‘This is really not good.’
>   ‘It is determined,’ Chiron announced.
>   All around me, campers started kneeling, even the Ares cabin, though they didn’t look happy about it.
>   ‘My father?’ I asked, completely bewildered.
>   ‘Poseidon,’ said Chiron. ‘Earthshaker, Stormbringer, Father of Horses. Hail, Perseus Jackson, Son of the Sea God.’
>
> <sub><sup>Percy Jackson and the Lightning Thief</sup></sub>

Comment: Psst, post a summary statement as a header (do --- on the line under it) and put in a picture, and I'll give you a bounty.

Comment: I can do a short summary on the top and a line under it, but for a picture I fear I will have to pass (not sure where I would get one of the scenes they never shot for the film itself^^')

Comment: I've taken the liberty of adding a book quote and rewording your answer a bit. If you think I've gone too far, hit the rollback button.

Comment: I've added a picture from the graphic novel and put up a header.  You'll still get a bounty.

Comment: @valorum no harm done ;)

Comment: @axelrod cool tnx. didn't even know that there is a graphic novel out there! (I only knew of the books and the films)

Comment: I'm not sure this is true.  Powers generally seem to manifest by age, not necessarily after being acknowledged.

Comment: A couple pages earlier he healed himself by standing in water, quite a bit before being acknowledged.

Comment: @DaveJohnson Do you have a page number? (or do you mean in the graphic novel)

Comment: @Thomas no page number. On my Kindle edition it says location 1537 of 4850. It was a few swipes before your quote.

Comment: @DaveJohnson tnx will look there tomorrow or saturday (need to read up in the book and see there). If he used that power defore then its "just" the power level that is different to before acknowledgement (usually at least).

Answer (score 0):

Water is soothing. Most injuries you get aren't something you really notice healing up unless they are severe, especially as a kid. You'll notice having a scratch or a bruise and then forget about it. By the next time you remember it's gone. It's not something you or anyone else is going to notice. And the things that someone might notice, like severe bruises or things that stay around... Some people don't bruise easy and they heal quickly when they do so, again, not something you're going to notice or think is odd. Things that stick around for a while, like bug bites, most people just ignore and if you've never had them you wouldn't think it's odd.

You might hear someone complaining they get bitten all the time and you'll comment that you don't or something and you and they'll pass it off as just luck, not magic powers of healing.

So... Yeah, if he hasn't had any severe lacerations or other major injuries, which he likely hasn't, it is completely within the realm of possibility that he and others would not really ever take notice.

Comment: Surely he has cut himself before and after a bath, have it gone. That would be a pretty big deal. I remember as a kid skinning my knee and how much it hurt having a bath. Percy on the other hand would have had the wound healed instantly.

Comment: @KyloRen Not all kids have that experience and even in that situation there is the fact that when you get such injuries there is blood and whatever covering it so you don't know the full extent. Now when he/someone else goes to wash it to treat it they'd find that the extent of the injury wasn't bad at all in their perception. "but there's no damage" you say. They'd just presume that the skin is sticking together and sealing it and best not poke at it to make it worse. It's happened to me and people around me and since these are one offs or people trying to hide it Percy wouldn't realize it

Comment: I highly doubt that someone has not injured themselves up until the age of what Percy is. 16 year old? Even a scratch instantly healed would ring alarm bells.

Comment: @KyloRen Why? All the cuts and such that I had, which were more than the average kid, were all avoidable or of the level of damage that could be easily explained away if for some reason I never seemed to have cuts for more than a day... And the materials and safety measures kids have as Percy was growing up would have been adequate to even prevent those injuries even if he wasn't relatively sheltered which he was. Also any major injury would be bandaged and that's another layer of obscuration that would be in place to prefent Percy from realizing.

Comment: Hold on, you are saying you have never been injured?

Comment: @KyloRen No. I am saying that even someone like me who has more cuts and scrapes, and scratches, and gouges of flesh taken out of them than a normal kid growing up the injuries were of a level that if they vanished I wouldn't be like "OMG I have magic powers" You are asking how could he not realize this, not how could he go his entire life withouth getting injured. The answer is, it's fairly easy to live a life of getting no injuries or low level enough that you're not going to notice them magically vanish if they did in most cases.

Comment: If a cut was there before he had a bath and then was gone afterwards , I am pretty sure he would notice something like that. No one has cuts or scrapes that are there before a bath and not there after, Not to mention in the movies he seems to know that the cuts are healing.

Comment: Have to agree with Kylo here. Cuts healing more quickly than expected is not at all the same as cuts, even bad ones, healing completely in the ten minutes it takes to take a shower. Scraping your knees or hands, probably the most common kid injuries, is not something you notice when you get it and then don’t think about anymore—it stings every time you accidentally touch something the wrong way, and it takes a good while to heal. If any bruise you ever got disappeared completely as soon as you took a shower, that would be something you’d notice. Definitely.

Comment: Getting into the bath would sting and then you'd feel soothed and then most kids would get out of the bath and go to bed and forget all about it. Scrapes, they'd not know the scrape was bad due to it healing while being treated before they'd notice. What kind of person sits there and looks at their cuts and wounds so much? Most people would not so why are you thinking he would? And from what we know he's not an kid that is prone to getting many injuries to begin with so even if he were the chances of his noticing are greatly diminished by that fact alone.

Comment: Do you have any evidence that “most people" do not look at their cuts and bruises? In my experience, most people (especially children) are _constantly_ touching or picking at bruises and scabs. If you fall and scrape off most of the skin on your knee and then 20 minutes later, your knee is completely healed again, you would notice. People don’t just injure themselves and then take one look at the injury and never notice it again. That’s just not how the real world works.

Comment: Actually it pretty much is. Again scrapes you wouldn't notice as I have explained several times. Other cuts and bruises, you only look at them to see how bad they are and to check on their progress of healing. People do pick at their scabs, but in this case there wouldn't be any so that's moot. When people do look at theirs injuries are more not doing it to look at it, but are doing something else, are reminded they have it and then are like "oh that's still there" but if it's not there to begin with you wouldn't look often.

Comment: You all assume he would recognize his quick healing in water as something special. If it always happened, how could he? That is just how the world works. A toddler seeing a human fly would not freak out [to a kid the whole world is strange and new after all], an adult would (or think he's having a dream and happened to land in Metropolis). The fact that injuries take time to heal is learned not instinctive. So his mom would know the reason of course, but she's not going to say anything to him, ergo: he assumes that's how it is.

Comment: @KyloRen In the films he is supposed to be 16, only 11 in the books though, which makes also quite a bit of a difference regarding life experiance...

Comment: Thomas' answer suggests that there's a fully canon reason for it. It's not just that he hasn't noticed (which would make him the most clueless/lucky person in history), it's that this is the first time he's been "acknowledged" by his dad, a key moment in a demigod's life.

Comment: @Valorum Didn't want to address but that's wrong. The healing and the acknowledgement are not the same. It's been a year since I read it but I'm fairly certain he shows healing powers before this point in the book

Comment: The quote about ten lines before is "*‘I came as fast as I could. I was about to jump in, but…’ She shrugged. ‘You didn’t need help.’
Then she noticed my wounded arm. ‘How did you do that?’
‘Sword cut,’ I said. ‘What do you think?’
‘No. It was a sword cut. Look at it.’
The blood was gone. Where the huge cut had been, there was a long white scratch, and even that was fading. As I watched, it turned into a small scar, and disappeared.
‘I – I don’t get it,’ I said.*". Admittedly I know nothing about this series, but that seems quite definitive

Comment: There are also zero mentions of the word "heal", "healing", "healed", "wound", "bath", "cut", "cuts", "soothe", "repair", "restore", "treat" or "knit" before this point in the novel.

Comment: @Valorum He notices himself being healed and then after he is recognized. These are 2 events and aren't reliant on each other. It's pretty clear throughout the series that the powers are not reliant on being recognized as that is a major plot point, that children from the big 3 are not supposed to even exist. We see others who are born of the big 3, who have powers, but were never recognized, so it's pretty obvious that they are separate events. Also the big symbol would not be needed if it were related.

Comment: @Durakken - I shall leave that for you to argue out with those who've actually read the books. From my very (very) cursory glance through that chapter, it seems awfully co-incidental that he's discovered his healing power at practically the same time that the big glowing trident appears over his head.

Comment: @Valorum He, as well as others, are shown to have powers before that point. This is just the first time he has used it to the point of notice considering he took a big hit. That big hit was in doing what likely got him recognized and that is being brave, a good leader, etc. which is a far more reasonable considering that recognition could have lead to worse consequences and Poseidon had to be certain, before recognizing him. Poseidon was said to be helping Percy along in life at other points too and there is no reason to think the healing stuff is a necessary part of the recognition part.